# C# Display Formatted Content of Array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am trying to display an array which by itself is no issue. However, I want to add an `If statement`, so that if the current iteration of the `score[]` array that is being displayed is equal to 300 then it will put a `*` after it. Something like `300*`

Also the array needs to display highest to lowest which I am doing by reversing the display at the moment it is in the array as lowest to highest. I was thinking about using a swap to reverse the order but if I don't have to then I would like to solve it this way.

So far I am getting

```
400
332
300*
300
```

or in another way I tried, I got

```
0
0
300*
300
250 
221
```

I am just having issue with display and output.

```
static void Output(int iteration, int[] score, string[] player, double average)
    {   //opening output 
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t****** OUTPUT ******");
        Console.WriteLine("\nScores for this game.\n");

        if (score[iteration - 1] == 300)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} score was {1}*", player[iteration - 1], score[iteration - 1]);
        }

        for (int i = iteration; i <= MAX_SIZE_ARRAY; i--)
        {             
                //iterates through the loop to display all the players name then score
                Console.WriteLine("{0} score was {1}", player[i], score[i]);
        }
        //displays high, low, and average score
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe high score was {0} with {1} points", player[iteration - 1], score[iteration - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine("The low score was {0} with {1} points", player[0], score[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("The team average score was {0}", average);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you just need to move your if statement inside the for loop?

Comment: I did try that but it gave undesired results also

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data coming in? Also in your for loop does it need to be i > 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the if statement inside the loop should work:

```
for (int i = iteration; i <= MAX_SIZE_ARRAY; i--)
 {             
   //iterates through the loop to display all the players name then score
   if (score[iteration - 1] == 300)
     Console.WriteLine("{0} score was {1}*", player[iteration - 1],                                  score[iteration - 1]);
   else
     Console.WriteLine("{0} score was {1}", player[i], score[i]);
 }
```

My guess is this a school assignment to make a bowling scoring system? One suggestion would be to link player names with their scores by using a list or array of KeyValuePair, Tuple, or your own Struct definition rather than two separate arrays. Having them separate will lead to issues where they wont match up due to a bug. (removed from one and not the other, sorting changes in one, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

check `score[i] == 300` inside the loop:

```
for (int i = iteration; i <= MAX_SIZE_ARRAY; i--)
 {             
   if (score[i] == 300)
     Console.WriteLine("{0} score was {1}*", player[i], score[i]);
   else
     Console.WriteLine("{0} score was {1}", player[i], score[i]);
 }
```